# Matrix with elements built from vector inner products

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given a set of $N$ vectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^N$ in $\mathbb R^d$ (with $N > d$), we construct

$E_{i,j} = \langle v_i, v_j\rangle$

Is there a name for this kind of matrix? I am especially interested in its spectral properties (I know that a lot of eigenvalues are zero by linear dependence of the $v_i$).

Comment: [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)